# вывести треугольники со звездочек (размер указывает пользователь)

Tags: javascript

я сделал, но нужно сделать без метода document.write

```js
function rightTriangle(starsNumber) {
  for (var stars = 0; stars < starsNumber; stars++) {
    for (var line = 0; line < starsNumber; line++) {
      if (line >= stars) document.write('*');
      else document.write('&nbsp&nbsp');
    }
    document.write('<br>');
  }
}
let size;
size = prompt('Enter size');
rightTriangle(size);
```

Пример если пользователь ввел рамзер 3

```
***
 **
  *
```

За ранее спасибо, если сможете с комментариями буду очень признателен

Comment: За что спасибо?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Выводить будем в элемент `<pre>`, поэтому нам достаточно получить чистую строку с треугольником.

Для этого мы создаём массив с количеством элементов, равным количеству строк, и заполняем его строчками.

В каждой строке сначала идут пробелы в количестве, равном номеру строки (ноль в нулевой строке и т.д.), потом идут звёздочки в количестве, равном остатку при вычитании номера строки из количества звёздочек (в нулевой строке будут все звёздочки, потом на одну меньше и т.д.).

```js
function rightTriangle(starsNumber) {
  return Array.from(
    { length: starsNumber },
    (_, index) => `${' '.repeat(index)}${'*'.repeat(starsNumber - index)}`,
  ).join('\n');
}

const triangle = rightTriangle(+prompt('Enter size'));

const pre = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('pre'));

pre.textContent = triangle;
```

Вариант без массива с выводом в консоль.

```js
function rightTriangle(starsNumber) {
  let str = '';
  for (let line = 0; line < starsNumber; line++) {
    str += `${' '.repeat(line)}${'*'.repeat(starsNumber - line)}\n`;
  }
  return str;
}

const triangle = rightTriangle(+prompt('Enter size'));

console.log(triangle);
```

Comment: Спасибо за такой вариант(вариант очень сильно крутой), но хотелось бы попроще, как можно максимально проще(без массивов) используя только циклы.

Comment: вывод должен быть через console.log

Comment: @DenisTynenyk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CU5PsW3f9So&t=247s

Comment: @DenisTynenyk Добавил вариант без массива с выводом в консоль.

Answer (score 5):

```js
document.body.textContent = Array(+prompt()).fill().map((x,i,a)=>" ".repeat(i)+"*".repeat(a.length-i)).join("\n")
```

```css
body { white-space: pre; font-family: monospace; }
```